# codeigniter return null from dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I have drop-down in my view

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<select id="news_category" name="ed_news_category"  class="form-control">
  <?php
  foreach ($news_category_data as $ncat ) {?>
    <option
    <?php
    if($cat_for_news->nc_id == $ncat->nc_id) { echo "selected" ;}
     ?>
       value="<?php $ncat->nc_id ?>"><?php echo $ncat->nc_id ," - ", $ncat->news_category_name ?>
     </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

and in my controller get a value of drop-down and its returned empty

```
'news_category_id' => string '' (length=0)
```

my controller is:

```
$ed_ne_data = array(
    'titel' => $this->input->post('ed_news_title') ,
    'content' => $this->input->post('ed_news_content') ,
    'news_category_id' => $this->input->post('ed_news_category') ,
    'img_url' => $this->newsModel->getNewsToEdit($ed_ne_id)->img_url,
    'created_at' => date("Y-m-d")
);
```

how i solved it

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you forget to echo value in option value

Change

```
 value="<?php $ncat->nc_id ?>"
```

To

```
 value="<?php echo $ncat->nc_id ?>"
              ^^^^^
```